# Double join on a table on the same field

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I have 2 tables based on this structure :

```
airports : code,value
fly : idFly,date, codeAirport1, codeAiport2
```

codeAirport1 corresponds to takeoff and codeAirport2 corresponds to landing so they are different.
And I want to get the value for codeAirport1 and codeAirport2. I tried this :

```
SELECT v1.codeAirport1, v2.codeAiport2
From airports
LEFT  JOIN fly v1 ON airports.code = v1.codeAirport1
LEFT JOIN fly v2 ON airports.code = v2.codeAiport2;
```

but the job in Hadoop is infinite because reduce step are always running and never finish.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um, your query doesn't match your stated table structure.  Assuming `origin` and `dest` are different, your query won't return rows - they're both trying to be equal to the same `iata` value, which is obviously false; probably, you need to switch which of the tables is referenced twice.  Side note - why don't you have separate takeoff/landing times?

Comment: yes I forgot to edit the query. So I can't do it in one requests ?

Comment: Sure you can, but your query is currently expecting `v1.codeAirport1` to be equal to `v2.codeAiport2` in all cases (the airplane returned to the same airport?), which is probably false.  You need to switch which table is referenced twice.  And shouldn't your `SELECT` list be the values, anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be the other way around:

```
SELECT 
  fly.codeAirport1, 
  a1.value as valueAirport1,
  fly.codeAiport2,
  a2.value as valueAirport2
FROM
  fly
LEFT JOIN 
  airports a1 ON a1.code = fly.codeAirport1
LEFT JOIN 
  airports a2 ON a2.code = fly.codeAirport2
```

Comment: Could you at least explain **why**?  That's far more important than just saying "you need to do this".